# Creating custom apache solr search in drupal 7

Tags: apache, solr, drupal-7, lucene, drupal-views

I need to create a custom search, in which end-user will directly put his query in the text area like:

```
(field1:test1 AND field2:test2) OR field3:test3
```

This search will allow all the operator which are available in solr/lucen document(http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html).

I have tried to parse the string entered but not found it a proper solution, because for this first I will require to write complete algorithm to solve these and then create solr relevant query.

I have also tried using views exposed filter and https://www.isovera.com/blog/allow-advanced-lucene-solr-syntax-using-search-api-views to find any solution, but I didn't find anything.